# Can trade goods be used toward acquiring weapons/armor in special materials?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, special-materials

If I have, for example, adamantine as a trade good, can I use it toward purchasing an adamantine longsword?

[Adamantine trade good](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/goods-and-services/ue-more-gear-4/#table-glasses-metals-and-woods):

> Adamantine    1 lb.   300 gp  UE

[Adamantine weapon cost](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/special-materials#TOC-Adamantine):

> Weapon    +3,000 gp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**According to the rules, gp is GP, and an Adamantine Bar isn't GP, though it may as well be.**

Rules as Written, you must have the GP to spend to get something from a merchant.  However, most merchants will (see PFS01-01) honor trade bars as their GP equivalent.  The catch to this is that if you're capable of crafting, there's nothing stopping you from getting ten bars of Adamantine and forging the weapon yourself if your GM allows it, though 3,000gp results in a crafting time of over three weeks.

Comment: What is PFS01-01?

Comment: PFS stands for Pathfinder Society. PFS01-01 is scenario 1 of Season 1, although Season 1 isn't always referred to that way.

Comment: @Adam Wells You mean, 3-4 bars of Adamntine, since crafting uses raw materials equal to a third of the price. Not to mention, with a price of 30000sp, even with a skill bonus of +30 and a 20 on the die every time, it's still going to take over 50 weeks to make one.

Comment: @YogoZuno Ah, the beauty of Pathfinder, where it only takes 3.5 pounds of Adamantine to forge an 8-pound greatsword. (Or, on the other end, it takes 3.5 pounds of Adamantine to forge a 1-pound dagger)

Comment: @yogozuno I mean, yeah. That's a thing. I am kind of lazy so I refer to it with the code. Anyway, an NPC on that is called out as explaining the use of trade bars and how they can be used to do large transactions quickly.

Comment: @adam wells I've actually never seen anyone refer to Season 1 that way, and the code you've listed makes it a little ambiguous as to which scenario you mean - the name would be more useful, perhaps?

Comment: @Delioth Nobody ever accused the D&D 3.x crafting system of making sense. Take a look at some of the examples used in the Alternate Crafting system at http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/craft

Comment: @Delioth let's start from the fact that 8 pound sword hardly makes sense, unless that's with scabbard, and even then it is heavy.  [According to this site](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-weight-of-the-heaviest-non-ceremonial-sword-on-record) realistic max is about 5.5 lbs. It is a game, not reality simulator. It just needs to make enough sense to be fun, and that's it :)

Comment: This discussion needs to go to chat, its getting off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Trade goods are not just as-good-as gold, they are better than gold. While prices are given in gp for rules purposes, the CRB makes clear that trade goods, no gold, are the preferred currency of nearly all people.  Gp is explicitly an unusual currency, and may not always be accepted but precious metals, gems, sheep, wheat, canvas, regular metals-- these and all other trade goods are accepted by merchants everywhere and most non-merchants as well.

Your adamantine bar is better than gold in this transaction -- especially if you are buying from a blacksmith who forges those swords.